# Accessing the Unix environment from emacs and Cocoa apps in OS X Mountain Lion

Tags: macos, unix, emacs, osx-mountain-lion, cocoa

I use emacs on my mac, I install the Cocoa version of emacs using homebrew.
One problem is that in order to see the "Unix path" I had to replicate my path from `.profile` to `.MacOSX/environment.plist`

I do it with this in my .profile:

```
# PATH for emacs and cocoa apps
/etc/profile begin
if [ -x /usr/libexec/path_helper ]; then
  eval `/usr/libexec/path_helper -s`
  defaults write $HOME/.MacOSX/environment PATH "$PATH"
fi
```

And that used to work, but it stopped working when I installed Mountain Lion. I can't find any manual that says that they've changed it on this version.

Does anyone know how to see the unix path from cocoa applications on Mountain Lion?

Comment: Hm, IIRC they planned on deprecating `environment.plist` a long time ago. You can try to use `/etc/launchd.conf` or `launchctl setenv` instead, but your mileage may vary. I'll check this out tomorrow.

Comment: oh thank you! Apparently the .MacOSX/environment file has been deprecated (it'd be nice if Apple had a nice article explaining the situation and what to do instead). I replaced the code in the .profile with `launchctl setenv PATH $PATH` and it works, but I need to reboot to any changes on the path.

Answer (score 4):

To formally answer this question: It could be that `.MacOSX/environment.plist` does not work anymore (?) or at least not reliably. It never worked for apps launched by Spotlight. It is documented though: [Runtime Configuration Guidelines: Environment Variables](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPRuntimeConfig/Articles/EnvironmentVars.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002093-BCIJIJBH)

The alternative to that is using `launchctl`, which will make environment variables accessible to GUI apps. For example, this copies your shell's `PATH` to the environment:

```
launchctl setenv PATH $PATH
```

For any changes to `$PATH`, you will have to restart the affected apps. You do not need to reboot if you use above syntax. If, however, you change `/etc/launchd.conf`, you will need to reboot. See also: [Setting environment variables in OS X? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/135688/setting-environment-variables-in-os-x)

Comment: It does not really work! I don't get. It sometimes it does and sometimes it doesn't. `launchctl getenv PATH` from an emacs shell returns the right thing, but `echo $PATH` has the wrong path in it!. For the moment I do `(setenv "PATH" (shell-command-to-string "launchctl getenv PATH"))' at the beginning of the `.emacs` file, but it is a hack!

Comment: Hm. I have never used the Cocoa emacs, and for me the `.MacOSX` version has always worked, at least until 10.6 (and I haven't needed it afterwards). Maybe you can update your question with your current status – especially with emacs – and others can have a look?